# why can't I use ":=" to assign values in this situation?

Tags: go

just like this demo:

```golang
func main() {
    type test struct {
        string
        int
    }

    t := test{}
    t.string, i := foo() // compile error: ',', ';', <assign op>, new line or '}' expected, got ':='
}

func foo() (string, int) {
    return "", 0
}
```

it will cause compile error like "',', ';', , new line or '}' expected, got ':='", "Syntax error: unexpected end of statement, expecting := or = or comma"

I need to do like this:

```golang
func main() {
    type test struct {
        string
        int
    }

    t := test{}
    var i int
    t.string, i = foo()
}

func foo() (string, int) {
    return "", 0
}
```

Can someone tell me why?

Comment: [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) -- `ShortVarDecl = IdentifierList ":=" ExpressionList .` and `IdentifierList = identifier { "," identifier } .`. The `t.string` is *not* an [`identifier`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#identifier), it is a [`selector expression`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors). And [`assignments`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments) allow expressions on the LHS, ShortVarDecl doesn't.

Comment: @super yes, you can do that. Programs are full if it all the time. `a, err := something(); b, err := something_else()` is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@mkopriva's answer is correct but I think it's worth clarifying this as this confused me as a newbie also.

### tl:dr

The language is defined this way.

### How is it defined this way?

If you look at the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations)

> Unlike regular variable declarations, a short variable declaration may
> redeclare variables provided they were originally declared earlier in
> the same block (or the parameter lists if the block is the function
> body) with the same type, and at least one of the non-blank variables
> is new.

It *would* appear your syntax *should* work.

```golang
type test struct {
    string
    int
}

t := test{}
t.string, i := foo()
```

But the key point is that one is a declaration *and* assignment, and one is just an assignment.

`:=` is the short form of declaring a variable and `=` is the assignment operator. Despite looking deceptively similar, the language spec allows them to do different things.

If you look at the spec for [Assignments](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments) you can trace the valid syntax to be:

```golang
PrimaryExpr =
    Operand |
    Conversion |
    MethodExpr |
    PrimaryExpr Selector |
    PrimaryExpr Index |
    PrimaryExpr Slice |
    PrimaryExpr TypeAssertion |
    PrimaryExpr Arguments .
```

`Operand` contains the syntax for an `identifier` (variable). You can see that both `Operand` and `PrimaryExpr Selector` are valid to be assigned to. The syntax `t.string` is a selector, *not an identifier*.

Looking at the spec for [short declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) and find the list of valid syntax:

```golang
ShortVarDecl = IdentifierList ":=" ExpressionList .
/.../
IdentifierList = identifier { "," identifier } .
```

You can see the *only* thing that is allowed on the LHS is an identifier.